# How can I remove 'U.S.' from Menubar on the lock screen?

Tags: menu-bar, input-source, lockscreen

I have only one language and input source set up but I'm still seeing Input Source icon ("U.S.") on the lock screen. Also, "Show Input menu in menu bar" is toggled off in settings.

Is there a way to remove the Input Source icon from the lock screen entirely?

I would appreciate any help!

---

[image: Input Source icon ("U.S.") on the lock screen]

[image: Language & region settings]

[image: Keyboard settings]

Comment: If you option-drag it off the menu bar, does it remove itself?

Comment: @MarcWilson  The "Show Input menu in menu bar" setting is toggled off, so there is no icon in the menu bar. 

The icon is only present on the lock screen, and you cannot drag anything off of the menu bar on the lock screen.